# How to show available options with evil-leader? (like spacemacs)

Tags: evil

Spacemacs has a nice ability to show available keys when pressing the leader key.

How can bound leader keys be displayed with `evil-leader` ?

Or is this only available via a different package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [which-key](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key).

Answer (score 1):

A combination of evil, which-key and general has served me well.

I'm still new, but I cobbled a little something together by enabling the following (as an example):

```
(counsel-mode 1)
(evil-leader-mode 1)
(evil-mode 1)

(general-define-key
:keymaps '(normal insert emacs)
:prefix "SPC"
:non-normal-prefix "M-SPC"
"b" '(:ignore t :which-key "buffers")
"f" '(:ignore t :which-key "files")
"fed" 'find-user-init-file
"fek" (find-file "~/.emacs.d/keybindings.el")
"f f" 'counsel-find-file
"b k" 'buf-move-up
"b j" 'buf-move-down
"b h" 'buf-move-left
"b l" 'buf-move-right
"b d" 'kill-buffer-and-window)
```

You should be able to follow pretty well with the example and the documentation on the general.el's github site on how to make things work.